# Can't generate proper file in python

Tags: python-2.7, file

I'm trying to generate a new file based on an existing one containing only lines with some predefined text. I have:

```
with open("steps_shown_at_least_once.log", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.find("Run program"):
            output = open('run_studio.txt', 'a')
            output.write(line)
            output.close()
```

for some reason this generates an identical file. However the **Run program** that I'm searching for is not located in every row of the old file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line.find('Run program') returns the index of a the string.

> **Return Value**
>   Index if found and -1 otherwise.

Found here: [Python String find() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)

Instead of `line.find("Run program"):` write `if "Run program" in line:`